# ASP.Net - Conditional formatting of label - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a label on a form (lblIRafr) which I am assigning a value to as below:

```
lblIRafr.Text = irAverageFailureRate & "%"
```

I am generating the value to assign to this label with the below code:

```
Dim irAverageFailureRate As String = (CDbl(irTotalFailureRate / 2).ToString("0.00"))
```

I am then formatting the label so that if irAverageFailureRate is above 3, it will make the text bold and red, otherwise the text will be bold and green. I am doing this as below:

```
If irAverageFailureRate > "3.00" Then
        Dim l As Label = lblIRafr
        l.Font.Bold = True
        l.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    Else
        Dim l As Label = lblIRafr
        l.Font.Bold = True
        l.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    End If
```

This is working fine on numbers between 0 and 9.99 but as soon as irAverageFailureRate reaches 10.0, the label is formatted bold and green instead of red and I'm not entirely sure why.

Any help gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: why you are comparing strings instead of doubles itself .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are comparing string to string.

"10.00" is less than "3.00" since the first char "1" is less than "3"

"2.00" is less than "3.00" since the first char "2" is less than "3"

"9.99" is greater than "3.00" since the first char "9" is greater than "3"

Convert `irAverageFailureRate` to double before comparing:

```
If Double.Parse(irAverageFailureRate) > 3.0 then
    ' red
Else
    ' green
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Makes sense now and is working correctly